# Reform tasker intent to shell

Tags: android, shell, adb, tasker

So this is a problem I want help with:

Reform a Tasker task into a android ADB version of it.

```
<TaskerData sr="" dvi="1" tv="4.9u4m">
<Task sr="task21">
<cdate>1461327416340</cdate>
<edate>1522266060604</edate>
<id>21</id>
<nme>[APP]_PowerAmp_FwdAlbum</nme>
<pri>7</pri>
<Kid sr="Kid">...</Kid>
<Action sr="act0" ve="7">
<code>877</code>
<Str sr="arg0" ve="3">com.maxmpz.audioplayer.API_COMMAND</Str>
<Int sr="arg1" val="0"/>
<Str sr="arg2" ve="3"/>
<Str sr="arg3" ve="3"/>
<Str sr="arg4" ve="3">cmd:6</Str>
<Str sr="arg5" ve="3"/>
<Str sr="arg6" ve="3"/>
<Str sr="arg7" ve="3"/>
<Str sr="arg8" ve="3"/>
<Int sr="arg9" val="2"/>
</Action>
<Img sr="icn" ve="2">
<nme>hd_ab_navigation_forward</nme>
</Img>
</Task>
</TaskerData>
```

This is an example task of such kind.

The problem is the info from here https://qiita.com/niusounds/items/e5d2209deb297942b566
or here
http://tomazwang.logdown.com/posts/1743911/android-mock-braodcast-intent-with-adb
didn't really help.

I tried any possible combination from start broadcast to start service, but I seem to be missing something.

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Comment: what is it exactly that you want to do? and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind.
Got the answer:
Used "krow.dev.scheme" to find the proper intent (by experimening), then read out "/data/data/krow.dev.scheme/files/default.realm.managment/log_b" et voilà, done)

> sudo "am broadcast
> 'intent:#Intent;action=com.maxmpz.audioplayer.API_COMMAND;package=com.maxmpz.audioplayer;i.cmd=1;end'"

That will for example make poweramp play/pause
(Sudo can obviously be substitited with su)